# Compare Dynamic CheckBox Array

Tags: vb.net

I'm writing the code for a program in VB.net that should do the following:
The program should read a .txt file and dynamically create checkboxes (or perhaps a CheckBoxList) for the amount of questions in the .txt file.

So, personally, I made a button, which when clicked reads the .txt file.   After that, I did a loop detecting the Questions(and the number of it) and depending on that I made 2 buttons for each question( representing yes or no).

The problem lies here: How to implement `If checkbox1.Checked = True Then checkbox2.Checked = False`. My idea was to make two checkbox arrays and compare them(whether first elements are checked), but I do not know if it's correct or if it's even possible.

The relevant code is the following:

```
Dim xRead As System.IO.StreamReader
xRead = File.OpenText("survey.txt")
'Dim counter As Integer
Dim line As String
Dim counter1 As Integer
Do Until xRead.EndOfStream
  line = xRead.ReadLine()
  TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & line & vbCrLf
  If line.Contains("Question") Then
    counter1 = counter1 + 1
    Dim offset1 As Integer
    offset1 = 500
    Dim offset2 As Integer
    offset2 = 200 + offset2
    'counter = counter + 1, we use this at first to see if it works.
    Dim checkBox1 As New CheckBox()
    Me.Controls.Add(checkBox1)
    checkBox1.Location = New Point(offset1 + 50, offset2)
    checkBox1.Checked = False
    checkBox1.Size = New Size(100, 20)
    Dim array1(counter1) As CheckBox
    array1(counter1) = checkBox1
    Dim checkBox2 As New CheckBox()
    Me.Controls.Add(checkBox2)
    checkBox2.Location = New Point(offset1, offset2)
    checkBox2.Size = New Size(100, 20)
    Dim array2(counter1) As CheckBox
    array2(counter1) = checkBox2
    offset2 = 50 + offset2 - 200
  End If
Loop
xRead.Close()
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. I am really sorry for the long post beforehand.

**Edit:**
What if I wanted to have 1 question at a time and some questions had different answers(so checkboxes as well, for instance Q1 has answers Yes/No, but Q2 has answers Agree/Disagree/Not Sure, etc) how would I do that? 
The result I get with what I've done so far is that only the last Question is posted. I've done the following:

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
Dim counter1 As Integer
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
Button1.Click
    Dim xRead As System.IO.StreamReader
    xRead = File.OpenText("survey.txt")
    'Dim counter As Integer
    Dim line As String
    Dim offset1 As Integer
    Dim offset2 As Integer
    Do Until xRead.EndOfStream
        line = xRead.ReadLine() & vbCrLf
        If line.Contains("Question") Then
            line = line + xRead.ReadLine()
            TextBox1.Text = line & vbCrLf
            line = xRead.ReadLine()
            If line.Contains("/") Then
                counter1 = counter1 + 1
                offset1 = 150
                offset2 = 200
                'counter = counter + 1, we use this at first to see if it 
works.
                Dim checkBox1 As New CheckBox()
                Me.Controls.Add(checkBox1)
                checkBox1.Location = New Point(offset1, offset2)
                checkBox1.Checked = False
                checkBox1.Size = New Size(100, 20)
                checkBox1.Text = "Yes"
                Dim checkBox2 As New CheckBox()
                Me.Controls.Add(checkBox2)
                offset1 = 250
                checkBox2.Location = New Point(offset1, offset2)
                checkBox2.Size = New Size(100, 20)
                checkBox2.Text = "No"
                AddHandler checkBox1.CheckedChanged, Sub()
                                                         checkBox2.Checked = Not checkBox1.Checked
                                                     End Sub
                AddHandler checkBox2.CheckedChanged, Sub()
                                                         checkBox1.Checked = Not checkBox2.Checked
                                                     End Sub
                Dim btn As Button = New Button
                btn.Location = New Point(offset1 + 200, offset2)
                btn.Name = "Next Question"
                btn.Text = "Next Question"
                Me.Controls.Add(btn)

                AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf Me.btn_Click
                TextBox1.Text = ""
            End If
        End If

    Loop
    xRead.Close()
End Sub
Private Sub btn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    Dim checkCount As Integer = 0
    For Each chkBox As CheckBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)()
        If chkBox.Checked Then
            checkCount += 1
        End If
    Next
    If checkCount = 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Next question.")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please answer the question and then hit Submit.")
        TextBox1.Text = ""

    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

After you create your two checkboxes, use an AddHandler to handle the CheckedChanged event of the boxes:

```
AddHandler checkBox1.CheckedChanged, Sub()
                                       checkBox2.Checked = Not checkBox1.Checked
                                     End Sub
AddHandler checkBox2.CheckedChanged, Sub()
                                       checkBox1.Checked = Not checkBox2.Checked
                                     End Sub
```

The arrays are not needed.

To check if every question has a check, move the counter1 declaration to the form scope level, and put this in your button's click event:

```
Dim checkCount As Integer = 0
For Each chkBox As CheckBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)()
  If chkBox.Checked Then
    checkCount += 1
  End If
Next
If checkCount = counter1 Then
  MessageBox.Show("all good")
Else
  MessageBox.Show("not all answered.")
End If
```

Comment: But I need more than two checkboxes. For instance, if the Survey contains 5 questions, I'll need 5 sets/pairs of checkboxes!

Comment: @Belf Go ahead and try it first.  If I understand your question, you are trying to toggle the checkboxes  for each question.

Comment: Lars! It's working. Thank you so much for the help.. You're amazing. One last thing,what if I wanted to add a button for submission that checks if all questions were answered?(So no blank checkbox for any question)

Comment: @Belf Updated the post.  This assumes no other checkboxes are on the form.

Comment: @Belf Why would you have a button for every question?  I assume there would be only one button at the bottom.

Comment: so that every time the user answers a specific question and it's clearer. Each question, now, could have different amount of answers ( scale 1 to 2, 1 to 3, or even image selection)